# Can't query accurate details with promethues custom counter

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to query the custom counter promethues metric but can't seem to find the right query. I would like to query the number of occurances in the last minute. For this I tried `sum(increase(my_counter[1m]))` as well as `sum(rate(my_counter[1m]))`. Neither seemed to be giving the accurate values. How can I query them instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to get accurate values (in the sense you expect) from Prometheus.

The immediate problem is that PromQL's `increase()` and `rate()` use extrapolation instead of actual available data. See [this Prometheus issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3806) for details. There are a number of workarounds for that, none of which are ideal. (E.g. you can take the increase over the desired interval *plus* `scrape_interval` and then adjust by dividing by the length of this interval and multiplying by the desired interval.)

The deeper problem is aliasing and there's not much you can do about that. Basically, because Prometheus is sampling your counter every `x` seconds/minutes you can't actually know the increase for any time range other than exactly between the instants those samples were collected. (And when you're asking Prometheus for `rate(x[1m])` you're actually asking for the increase between exactly *now* and *now* minus 1 minute, which will likely not align with any collected samples.) Not to mention there's jitter due to network latency, load, etc.

This latter issue doesn't excuse though (IMHO) PromQL's implementation of `rate()` and `increase()` and you should be able to get better numbers than what Prometheus is giving you. (Again, see the Prometheus issue linked above.)